# Google Apps Market Place Scope

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We would like to have our application deployed to Google market place app. As of now, our app uses email and profile scopes. For now, we only use the contats API of Google. In the future we would like to extend this to use calendar and drive apis. But for the first marketplace launch we would like to just use email and profile scopes.

Will build features incrementally with next releases of the app and extend the scopes.

1) Is this sufficient to meet the requirements of Google's review for a marketplace app ?

2) Also, please update which path should be taken for incremental change of scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gem like "https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2" for OAuth authentication and API usage with google. 
You can use "email" and "profile" scopes as of now. Later you can modify the scopes, "email" and "profile" scopes are default scopes if you add some other scopes to the provider it will get overwritten so for eg. if you want to use contacts api along with "email" and "profile" scopes add all three scopes.

provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"],

```
{
  :name => "google",
  :scope => "email, profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts,

}
```